# How to stub Android - Vision Barcode Scanner using espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-vision

I want automate BarCode Scanning using espresso/Appium ?

How Can I achieve this using ? Can I stub the image directly to the barcode scanner API to verify the decoder is working correct ?

Note : I don't want to give the text directly .

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to test barcode scanner API, then there is on need to use espresso/Appium frameworks.

Just implement unit test that will pass image or its `base64` formatted copy to your scanner API and check output with expected one.

That would make more sense then doing it via UI test framework.

Comment: Once The  App Scans barcode and gets text, our app connects to backend and sends the text . As a End to end we need to achieve this so I need a solution from any  UI  testing frameworks